# Set a parameter value in spring bean

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, cas

I am using CAS as a SSO solution in my web app, but my question is more spring related.  I use several authentication methods, DB, x509, etc...  and I have a requirement to display a message to the user as to what method of authentication worked or failed.

So I have some beans defined in my deployerConfigContext that do the authentication,  they look basically like this:

```
  <bean id="myDBUsernameResolver"
  class="my.resolver.UsernameToIDResolver"
  p:dataSource-ref="oracleDS" 
  p:sql = "select ID from blah blah blah" />
```

What I need is access to the HTTPSession, or the request parameters, or SOMETHING that I can access in my view jsp's.  I have NO access to the controllers, only the context file and the jsp.

Is there any way to inject anything into this bean (Session, Context, whatever) that I would have access to in the view?

I have tried the RequestContext, but I can only "get" I cannot "set."  I Cant seem to the the http session at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `RequestContextHolder` to get the `RequestAttributes` that should give you what you need. Although accessing it from database classes feels a bit yucky...

Comment: RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getAttributes().put("mymessage", "X"); Does not throw an error, that's good.  (I could not set parameters however)  but in my jsp I do request.getAttribute("mymessage")  and I am getting null.

Comment: Wait,  I am a dumba** I was using the wrong RequestContextHolder.  I was using the webflow package and not the web.context.request.  All works great now, thank you!